# How to add database query to list of string

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

Here, All I want is to store the values of every row to 1 variable with "#-#" as divider, and append them to list of string, but it isn't working, is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance

```
Private result As List(Of String)

Public Function GetFromDB()

    Dim values As String
    Try
        result = New List(Of String)
        myConn = New SqlConnection("SERVER=ABALTAZAR-L1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test;Integrated Security=True;")
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Item"
        myConn.Open()
        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
        values = String.Join("#-#", myReader.GetValue(0), myReader.GetValue(1),
                             myReader.GetValue(2), myReader.GetValue(3))
        result.Add(values)
        myConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Why? Perhaps your problem is better solved another way

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `while` loop in your code to retrieve each row from the `myReader`. One more thing, no need to use `string.Join` in your code, you can directly get concatenated column from your sql query using [Concat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function. Here is your modified code.

```
Try
    result = New List(Of String)
    myConn = New SqlConnection("SERVER=ABALTAZAR-L1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test;Integrated Security=True;")
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT(Column1, '#-#', Column2, '#-#', Column3) AS ResultCol FROM tbl_Item"
    myConn.Open()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
    While myReader.read()

        result.Add(myReader.GetValue(0))
    End While

    myConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex)
End Try
```